# How can I add two boxes in skeleton?

Tags: skeleton-css-boilerplate

Hello I am having little problem with responsive design. I don't know how to add image on the left and text on the right.

I am working with Skeleton.

[image: skeleton]

What should I do ?

**Update: Some Code**

```html
<section id="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="one_half ">
                <img class="picture-me" src="images/me.png" alt="">
                <!-- PICTURE SHOULD BE ON THE LEFT -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="one_half last">
             <h2 class="name"> Borut</h2> 
            <p>I am pixel-perfect...</p>
            <img class="shadow" src="images/shadow.png" alt="" width="537" height="1">
            <img class="quote-right" src="images/quote-right.png" alt="" width="29" height="21">
            <img class="quote-left" src="images/quote-left.png" alt="" width="29" height="21">
```

Comment: can you provide some code for what you have already tried

Comment: of course

<section id="about">
<div class="container">

<div class="container">
<div class="one_half ">
<img class="picture-me" src="images/me.png" alt="">
<!-- PICTURE SHOULD BE ON THE LEFT -->

</div>
</div>

<div class="one_half last">
<h2 class="name"> Borut</h2>

<p> I am pixel-perfect...</p>
<img class="shadow" src="images/shadow.png" alt="" width="537" height="1">
<img class="quote-right" src="images/quote-right.png" alt="" width="29" height="21" >

<img class="quote-left" src="images/quote-left.png" alt="" width="29" height="21" >

Comment: Please put the code in your post! And don't forget to format it! (People tend to get mad at unformated code!)

Comment: @Borut, Welcome to StackOverflow.  You'll get the best answers here by isolating single issues at a time by posting the least amount of code necessary to reproduce what you're having trouble with.  Someone else should be able to easily run your code and suggest changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [`Skeleton Grid`](http://www.getskeleton.com/#grid) layout system

You have to declare the layout within a `div` of class `container`.  Then add divs with the number of columns you'd like the to consume as classes.  To place columns side by side, use classes `alpha` and `omega`.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="twelve columns clearfix">
        <div class="six columns alpha">first block</div>
        <div class="six columns omega">second block</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added the following **css** to clarify the blocks

```css
.alpha {
    background-color: red;
}
.omega {
    background-color: green;
}
```

This will render as follows:

[image]

See this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/FYEKM/) to play around with the code a little

Comment: Thank you for your help KyleMit. But I have one question why clearfix, alpha and omega? Responsive is quite tricky for beginners.

I add this code and it's working. (can't post an answer because I need  reputation)

     <div class="container">
    <div class="five columns">
    </div>
    <div class="nine columns">
    </div>

Comment: You need `clearfix` because the six column classes are nested within a twelve column class.  Otherwise you don't need it.  Same thing with `alpha` and `omega` for nesting to indicate left and right (respectively).  See the code documentation for more info. Also, remember to accept answers that were helpful